# Android Studio "Can't play this video

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to play a video in my Android Studio emulator.

However, it shows dialog **Can't play this video**

I read a lot of similar questions on Stackoverflow, but none of those could fix it.

Hope anyone could help!

Thank you in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.demo);

        //MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);

        //mc.setAnchorView(videoView);

        //videoView.setMediaController(mc);

        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

and my logs show

```
02-09 01:19:41.811 8704-8704/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
02-09 01:19:41.817 8704-8704/? D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
02-09 01:19:41.842 8704-8719/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
02-09 01:19:41.845 8704-8718/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
02-09 01:19:41.847 8704-8704/? E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
02-09 01:19:41.848 8704-8704/? D/VideoView: Error: 1,-38
02-09 01:19:41.880 8704-8704/? E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
02-09 01:19:41.880 8704-8704/? D/VideoView: Error: 1,-38
```

Comment: Can you give some more details? Is an exception being thrown? What are you seeing in the logs?

Comment: 02-09 01:19:41.811 8704-8704/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
02-09 01:19:41.817 8704-8704/? D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
02-09 01:19:41.842 8704-8719/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
02-09 01:19:41.845 8704-8718/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
02-09 01:19:41.847 8704-8704/? E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
02-09 01:19:41.848 8704-8704/? D/VideoView: Error: 1,-38

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried waiting until the video view is prepared before starting the video?

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(mediaPlayer -> videoView.start());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);
    controller.setAnchorView(videoView);
    controller.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(controller);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(yourVideoPath));

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = videoView.getLayoutParams();
        float videoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
        float videoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();
        float viewWidth = videoView.getWidth();
        lp.height = (int) (viewWidth * (videoHeight / videoWidth));
        videoView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        playVideo();
      //  if (!videoView.isPlaying()) optional
        videoView.start();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    this.vidView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
    this.vidView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.numbers));
    MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
    vidControl.setAnchorView(this.vidView);
    this.vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
    this.vidView.start();
```